# Does a fusor emit dangerous radiation?

Tags: radiation, fusion, laboratory-safety

I noticed some online videos where people have built [these things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusor) in their house or garage.

Is it dangerous to do so?

The high voltage appears to be a potential hazard, but what about radiation -- what radiation do fusors emit and how dangerous is it?

Comment: Do you mean a fusor that actually achieves nuclear fusion, or one that only produces plasma?

Comment: @probably_someone I would be interested in the answer for each case.

Comment: High voltage arcs produce x-rays. Actual fusion will likely produce neutrons and gammas. I'll skip high-energy ions unless you want to bathe in the plasma. How much of each is left as an exercise to your local radiation tech.

Comment: A significant number of do-it-yourself fusors can use aneutronic reactions if you can get the precursors. But there is still prompt gamma as well as bremstrahullung.